# I'm new to maven and trying to create maven project in eclipse mars 4.5.1 in windows 7. I get an error stating "Failure to resolve dependencies"

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, groovy

```
<projectxmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/201/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.recommender</groupId>
  <artifactId>RecomenderApp</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>RecomenderApp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Eclipse shows an error in "jar". I tried installing groovy m2 eclipse, but that too failed. I tried looking at familiar posts but couldn't find a solution.  Please help

Comment: Is this a pasting error `<projectxmlns`? Should be `<project xmlns`.

Answer (score 0):

Once you added the dependency you need to update the project. This can be done by right clicking on the project name > maven > update project. This will refresh your project and the erross should go away. I had the same issue and was able to fix this way.